# Error in due loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable log method

Tags: python, time-series

When I use the below log function, i am getting the following error message in my jupyter notebook.
data1 = np.log(mdata).diff().dropna()
I tried to do cast but unable to get rid of this issue.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'log'

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b6f1878a7619> in <module>
----> 1 data1 = np.log(mdata).diff().dropna()

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable log method
```

mdata:

```
          Field1    Field2  Field3  Field4
TS              
2020-11-02 00:43:58.500 1595000 849332  205 69
2020-11-02 00:43:58.500 1408000 820332  198 51
2020-11-02 00:43:58.500 1770000 926054  213 56
2020-11-02 00:43:58.500 1760000 1002332 216 72
2020-11-02 00:43:58.500 1850000 957054  213 59
... ... ... ... ...
```

mdata.index:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000', '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000',
               '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000', '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000',
               '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000', '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000',
               '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000', '2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000',
               '2020-11-02 00:43:58.600000', '2020-11-02 00:43:58.600000',
               ...

               '2020-11-02 00:44:00.400000', '2020-11-02 00:44:00.500000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TS', length=199, freq=None)
```

Complete code is

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('inputdata.csv')
cols = ['Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4'] 
data_x = pd.to_datetime(data_x)
mdata = df1[cols]
mdata.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data_x)
data1 = np.log(mdata).diff().dropna()

The following statements are not executed due to the issue in the above statement

model = VAR(data)
results = model.fit(2)
results.summary()
```

Comment: It looks like one or more of your columns in mdata contains strings. Please post the output of `mdata.info()`.

Comment: Thanks. mdata contains string types . Please let me know how to handle this for log.                                                                                . <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 199 entries, 2020-11-02 00:43:58.500000 to 2020-11-02 00:44:00.500000
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   Field1  199 non-null    object
 1   Field2  199 non-null    object
 2   Field3  199 non-null    object
 3   Field4  199 non-null    object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 7.8+ KB

Comment: it worked when i convert object into float type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your data columns aren't a numeric type, and `numpy.log()` expects numeric data. You can convert the data to numeric values using `pandas.to_numeric()`

```
mdata = df1[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

or by converting the columns to a specific numeric type by using `DataFrame.astype()`

```
mdata = df1[cols].astype(float)
```

Comment: Getting the below type error  when I use pd.to_numeric(df1[cols])                                        TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: @Karthika - with multiple columns, I should have used `.apply()`. It should work now.